# Datepicker Angular Material: Input field format change when change value of the field

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, date-format

I'm using a **mat-date-rang-input** of **Angular Material**. I changed the date format of Angular Material from `MM/dd/yyyy` to `dd/MM/yyyy`, and that's works alright.

```html
<mat-form-field ngClass="filters_dateInterval">
    <mat-label>Date interval</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker" md-date-locale="{
                  inputDisplay: dd/MM/yyyy
                }}">
        <input matStartDate placeholder="Início" [(ngModel)]="dateStartFilterField" (valueChanges)="show($event)" />
        <input matEndDate placeholder="Fim" [(ngModel)]="dateEndFilterField" />
    </mat-date-range-input>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker" ngClass="filters_dateInterval__icon"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

However, when I tested the ui/ux, I noticed something unusual. After I wrote a date in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` and focused out, it lost that format and the date changed to  the format `MM/dd/yyyy`.

I tried changing the app.module.ts to include a provider to format the date.

```js
providers: [
    {
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      useValue: DATE_FORMAT_PTBR
    }
]
```

This is my `DATE_FORMAT_PTBR`:

```js
export const DATE_FORMAT_PTBR = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY'
  },
  formater: {
    dateInput: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
  }
};
```

I tried changing the `useValue` of providers to `'pt-BR'` too, but it did not affect the situation.

Comment: Have you tried using DatePipe e.g. <input matStartDate placeholder="Início" [(ngModel)]="(dateStartFilterField | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy')" (valueChanges)="show($event)" />

Comment: I tried now, but cannot is possible include pipe and date propertie in [(ngModel)].

Answer (score 1):

Correct the TS file as below,

```
import { MAT_DATE_FORMATS } from '@angular/material/core';

export const MY_DATE_FORMATS = {
    parse: {
      dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    },
    display: {
      dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
      monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
      dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
      monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY'
    },
};


 @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_DATE_FORMATS }
  ]
})
```

And HTML file as below,

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker ></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: it is not working for me

Comment: @gigaDIE what issue are you facing?